# How can I view the list of the booking requests that got declined by the host?

Tags: airbnb

I sometimes use Airbnb to rent a place. Typically booking requests are approved but from time to time, they get rejected,e.g. because the place isn't available. How can I view the list of the booking requests that got declined by the host?